# Is the gnome-screenshot modified for Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, screenshot

I am a big fan of gnome-screenshot on Ubuntu. When I press the <kbd>print</kbd> key on my keyboard, it captures the current screen and shows me a dialog asking what to do with the screenshot. 
Usually, I use it to copy screenshot to clipboard. Okay at the end, I like it.

Recently I installed ArchBang and installed gnome-screenshot. Added the keybindings. When I press the <kbd>print</kbd> key then it asks me first what to do i.e. capture full screen, select area to grab and a window to capture. So, I have to select it first and then it goes for capturing.

So, there is one extra step here. I want to ask if it is Ubuntu specific version of gnome-screenshot. If so, can I use it in ArchBang?

Thank you.

**Edit**:

In ArchBang, when I press the <kbd>PrintScr</kbd> button and then click on 'Copy to Clipboard' and then paste it somewhere, it works fine.
But, if I press <kbd>PrintScr</kbd> button and then click 'Copy to Clipboard' and close the dialog box and then try to paste, it doesn't work. 
And for the information, this thing worked great while on Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04. 
Don't exactly remember the gnome-screenshot version on Ubuntu.
But on ArchBang, it is gnome-screenshot 3.18.0.

Comment: On archbang it's 3.18.0. If needed, I'll tell you on the version on Ubuntu after some time.

Comment: No, that I can [look up](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-screenshot).

Comment: Hmm. No, on my Arch Linux, `gnome-screenshot` 3.18.0, running `gnome-screenshot` manually or pressing `PrtScrn` both result in an instant screenshot. So I guess it's got to do with how you set up the keybindings.

Comment: Can you tell me the keybindings (or command) for that?

Comment: When executing the following command to capture by area:

-> % `gnome-screenshot -a -c`


Got these errors:



** Message: Unable to select area using GNOME Shell's builtin screenshot interface, resorting to fallback X11.
** Message: Unable to use GNOME Shell's builtin screenshot interface, resorting to fallback X11.
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave

Answer (score 1):

Look at the package version names on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot. They all end in `*-[D]ubuntu[U]`, where `D` and `U` are digits and dots. If the placeholder `D` is not 0, it stands for the current *Debian* version of the package (meaning, the source package was modified for Debian), while `U` stands for the current *Ubuntu* version of the package (meaning it was altered for Ubuntu).

Some examples from the current state of the `gnome-screenshot` package in Ubuntu:

- `3.18.0-1ubuntu2`

  - upstream version: 3.18.0
  - Debian version: 1 (modified in Debian)
  - Ubuntu version: 2 (modified in Ubuntu)
- `3.16.2-0ubuntu3`

  - upstream version: 3.16.2
  - Debian version: n/a or 0 (not modified in Debian)
  - Ubuntu version: 3 (modified in Ubuntu)
- `3.4.1-0ubuntu1.1`

  - upstream version: 3.4.1
  - Debian version: n/a or 0 (not modified in Debian)
  - Ubuntu version: 1.1 (modified in Ubuntu)

We can conclude that Ubuntu doesn't use the unaltered upstream version of `gnome-screenshot`. Whether the changes affect the described behaviour, I cannot say.

Comment: Thank you explaining the concept. 
Assuming it to be true, then what's the significance of 'U'?



As the versions 3.18.0-1ubuntu2, 3.16.2-0ubuntu3, 3.4.1-0ubuntu1.1 contains the value of D = 1, 0 and 0 respectively. That means they are modified, not modified and modified for debian respectively.


Similarly, U = 2, 3, 1.1 respectively. Can you explain this to me which version is altered for Ubuntu and which is not out of these?

That would be very nice of you! Thank you.

Correct me if I got you wrong!

Comment: I added some examples.